# Need to enable Asus Instant On

Tags: windows-7, laptop

I have an Asus laptop, model U47A, with Windows 7. I accidentally closed the "Instant On" on my desktop, and now can't figure out how to re-enable that. Help?

Answer (score 0):

I have an Asus laptop, Instant On normally opens when you turn your computer on so restarting is an option otherwise you should be able to find it in its default location at
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\ASUS